# certificate and key in TLS 1.3

Tags: openssl, tls1.3

Hy guys,

I'm looking for evaluate the available cipher suites in TLS 1.3 with different Key Exchange and Authentication algorithms.
In particular I would like to try all the combination of ECDHE, DHE, DH, ECDH, RSA for Key Exchange and ECDSA,  RSA for Authentication.

I'm using `openssls_server` and `openssl s_clinet`
Two questions:

1. How can I set these commands to perform these operations?
2. Have I to create cert.pem and key.pem with specific algorithms?

Many thanks